# OpenCV Cannot connect to X server:

Tags: python, windows, opencv

When I try to use cv2.imshow(), I get an error saying that it can't conect to X server. I'm running this locally, using bash in Windows Command Prompt. No servers, no VPNS, etc.

Python 3.4, CV2 3.4

```
img = cv2.imread(fileName)
cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: "bash"... meaning WSL/WSL2 or any kind of container? because _native_ python and _native_ OpenCV, on Windows, would never even know what an "X server" is. they'd use Win32 GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue with bash on windows. had to install OpenCV using conda install instead. everything worked fine after the install. 
check out the anaconda page for details [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv). if you do have anaconda already you can run the code below in cmd to install opencv.

```
conda install -c conda-forge OpenCV
```

P.S: be sure to set anaconda as base in cmd by running the command else conda wont work.

```
C:\Users\{name}\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate base
```